# Htaccess go to file if it exist otherwise parameter

Tags: .htaccess

I got the following htaccess that makes

```
domain.com/param1/param2
```

to

```
domain.com/foo.php?bar=param1&baz=param2
```

But if the user goes to

```
domain.com/search
```

and search.php exist, I want to go to

```
domain.com/search.php
```

**.htaccess**

```
IndexIgnore */*

RewriteEngine on

#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^domain.com [NC]
#RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ http://domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [L]

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]*)$ foo.php?bar=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]*)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]*)$ foo.php?bar=$1&baz=$2 [L]

<Files .htaccess>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</Files>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
IndexIgnore */*

RewriteEngine on

#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^domain.com [NC]
#RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ http://domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]

RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ foo.php?bar=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ foo.php?bar=$1&baz=$2 [L,QSA]

<Files .htaccess>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</Files>
```

Comment: it is not a directory but a file "foo.php"

Comment: There is no redirect happening in these rules now. Open chrome Dev tool and check what redirect you are getting there.